# Python rerun the script after 5 minutes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a *tkinter* GUI table which load data from file.
I tried to do following code but not successful:

```
import schedule
import time
def job():
  root = tkinter.Tk()
  root.title("APP")
  root.configure(background='khaki')
  root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
  for r in range(11):
  for c in range(8):
   if c==0 and r==0:
    tkinter.Label(root, text="AAA",borderwidth=1,font=("Helvetica", 13)).grid(row=r, column=c)
  root.mainloop()

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)
```

it run but after 5 minute nothings change.

I need help to rerun the whose script again every 5 minutes to reload data to table.

how can I do that ?

Comment: Your `job` function never returns (or at least not until someone quits the GUI that it launches`. That's what `Tk.mainloop` _means_—loop forever until the GUI app is done.

Comment: Are you trying to launch a brand-new GUI every 5 minutes, or to create a GUI that gets updated every 5 minutes?

Comment: You need to either pause the tkinter loop while you update the table on the main thread, or you need to run it on a separate thread from where you update the table

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a refresh which ends in an [`after(...)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) callback to itself:

```
class my_frame(tk.Frame):

    def refresh(self):
        # do table update
        self.after(5*60*1000, self.refresh)  # 5 minutes in milliseconds
```

This will cause `root.mainloop()` to periodically refresh itself.

Without a custom frame:

```
def refresh():
    # do stuff
    root.after(5*60*1000, refresh)  # 5 minutes in milliseconds

root.after(5*60*1000, refresh)
```

Comment: Well, not just table update. The process need to rerun the whole script to get data again. How can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

tkinter has a function for that:

`widget.after(milliseconds, function, *args)`

So you can use:

```
root.after(300000, refreshFunction) # 300000 5 minutes in milliseconds
```